# Accessing Windows from Fedora after install?

Tags: fedora, boot, windows

I bought a desktop machine with Windows on it a couple of years ago, and then just last year or so installed Fedora on it from a disk I had (got it from a Linux magazine). Fedora works great, but I was never able to access Windows since then ever again. I'm interested in trying to get it to work now, so I'm taking another crack at it.

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://boringtalk.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/solving-the-problem-of-missing-windows-7-entry-in-grub2-on-fedora-18/) right now, but I'm not sure which partition to use (or if Windows still even works). The guide uses sda1 but I have a "Windows recovery environment" on there, not sure which one to use instead. This is the result of my `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D8E185CC-1266-4DC6-AEF5-459091253354

Device            Start          End   Size Type
/dev/sda1          2048      1640447   800M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2       1640448      2172927   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3       2172928      2435071   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4       2435072    317007871   150G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5     317007872    391127039  35.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6    1919969280   1953523711    16G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7     391127040    391129087     1M BIOS boot partition
/dev/sda8     391129088    392153087   500M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda9     392153088    425199615  15.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda10    425199616    530057215    50G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda11    530057216   1919969279 662.8G Microsoft basic data
```

Could someone please steer me in the right direction in getting Windows to boot up, or check if it's still even working?

Comment: Did you install dual boot fedora and windows? When you did dual boot. You should install windows first after that you installed Fedora.You should install GRUB bootloader.